# find the equation of the circle $x^2 +y^2 +ax +by = c$ passing through points $(6,8), (8,4), (3,9)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the equation of the circle $x^2 +y^2 +ax +by = c$ passing through points $(6,8), (8,4), (3,9)$.

How do I go about solving this? I don't have a textbook assigned so I'm not even sure what this relates to, but its the beginning of linear algebra. so I guess I'm supposed to construct some kind of system of equations...

Comment: Since it passes those 3 points, the coordinates of the center can be easily calculated..

Comment: ...........how?

Comment: Ans so does the radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute! You have 3 unknowns and 3 equations. For example, for $(6,8)$ you have that:

36 + 64 + 6a + 8b = c

Substituting the other two points you get:

80 + 8a + 4b = c

90 + 3a + 9b = c

From here you can choose your favorite method to find $a$,$b$ and $c$.

Comment: hmm yeah i just starting thinking that.. but how does that find me the equation of the circle?

Comment: what about using the elimination method or substitution method to find a or b?

Comment: oh so i find a,b,c and plug them back into original equation, then thats my equation! just needed a refresher hah.

Comment: @J L:well, once you know a,b and c you can plug them in in your original equation.

@usukidoll sure!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since it passes through $(6,8)$, $(8,4)$ and $(3,9)$ then you know that the equation will hold for those pairs $(x,y)$. i.e. solve for $a,b,c$:

$$\begin{cases}6^2 + 8^2 + 6a + 8b = c\\ 8^2 + 4^2 + 8a + 4b = c \\ 3^2 + 9^2 + 3a + 9b = c \end{cases}$$

Alternativelly, if a circle passes through the points $P, Q, R $, then the bisectors of $PQ$, $QR$ and $RP$ meet in the center of the circle.

Comment: The circles "passes through" the 3 points, they are not inside the circle. You might want to correct that..

Answer (score 1):

> $x^2 +y^2 +ax +by = c$ passing through points $(6,8), (8,4), (3,9)$.

It is given by the determinant:

$$ \begin{vmatrix} x^2 +y^2&  x& y& 1 \\ 6^2 + 8^2&  6& 8& 1 \\ 8^2 + 4^2&  8& 4& 1 \\ 3^2+9^2&  3& 9& 1\end{vmatrix} =0$$

Observe that equation has no $xy$ term, and coefficent of $x ^2$ and $y^2$ same, also notice that subbing $(x,y)$ as any of the point given solves the determinant. Hence it's the unique circle passing through three points QED.

[refer here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/geometry/sphere4pts.html)